# Does the associated Lie algebra determine a group?

Tags: lie-algebras, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and let $\Gamma_G(k)$ be the $k$th term of the lower central series of $G$. For each $k\geq 1$, set $\mathcal{L}_G(k)=\Gamma_G(k)/\Gamma_G(k+1)$ and $$\mathcal{L}_G:=\bigoplus_{k\geq 1}\mathcal{L}_G(k).$$ Then $\mathcal{L}_G$ has a graded Lie algebra structure induced from the commutator bracket on $G$.

My question:

To what extent can one determine $G$, if $\mathcal{L}_G$ is known? It is true that $G$ is uniquely determined by $\mathcal{L}_G$? If yes, how to find $G$, knowing $\mathcal{L}_G$?

Comment: How would you distinguish perfect groups?

Comment: Good point @AlexDegtyarev! Since there is no hope to determine $G$ completely, is there any weaker conclusion (or conclusion for certain types of groups) about $G$, after knowing $\mathcal{L}_G$?

Comment: There are 5-dimensional complex unipotent groups (or real/rational/discrete analogues) that are not isomorphic but whose associated Carnot algebras (i.e. the graded Lie algebra you construct) are not isomorphic. So even when $G$ is nilpotent, $\mathcal{L}_G$ is only some kind of 1st-order approximation of $G$.

Comment: @YCor I think you have a "not" too many in the statement (you write that the Lie algebras as not isomorphic).

Comment: Yes thanks Tobias I indeed mean "whose associated Carnot algebras (...) are isomorphic".

Comment: @YCor, I have not heard the term "Carnot algebra", do you have any reference for it?

Comment: It's the word the subriemannian geometers use. I think I heard it from Stefan Wenger. Google "Carnot Lie algebra". "graded" is possibly more common but it's hopelessly ambiguous.

Comment: @YCor, in most of the reference I read I have not seen the terminology "Carnot Lie algebra". Instead, the expression $E_0^{*}(G)$ is used. I am wondering why this particular notation is chosen. What does the $0$ mean there? Does $E_1^*(G)$, or more generally $E_n^*(G)$ make sense?

Comment: @Zuriel: several distinct communities use this notion of Lie algebras and use distinct terminologies with no attempt of unification. I tried to gather as many as possible of these terminologies... where did you find $E^*_0(G)$? never seen... and I don't know how to find it with Google.

Comment: @YCor, for example see F.R. Cohen - S. Prassidis: "On injective homomorphisms for pure braid groups, and associated Lie algebras", J. Algebra 298 (2006), no. 2, 363–370.

(available at the link http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404278) I am not sure if most algebraic topologists follow the same notation.

Comment: @Zuriel: OK but "Carnot Lie algebra" is a terminology, while "$E_0^*$" is a notation, these are two different things.

Comment: @YCor, thanks! I just wonder if there is any reason for this notation $E^*_0$. Do you know any reference that I can read about Carnot Lie algebra from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that even $Q_8$ and $D_8$ have isomorphic algebras. In fact, one can construct lots of similar pairs of $2$-nilpotent $2$-groups: roughly, the Carnot algebra captures a symplectic form only (which are all isomorphic), whereas the group itself depends on a quadratic extension of this form, and those differ by the $\operatorname{Arf}$-invariant.

Comment: For a 2-nilpotent 2-group, the Carnot algebra also captures the structure of the abelian 2-groups $G/[G,G]$ and $[G,G]$, which are not always 2-torsion (think of the Heisenberg group modulo $2^n$). Also even in the case these are 2-elementary (or in the case of complex unipotent groups), when the center is more than 1-dimensional, the classification is much more complicated than just one symplectic form: it corresponds to $k$-tuples of alternating forms up to simultaneous conjugation and these have a quite wild classification.

Comment: That's precisely what I mean (the direct generalization of $Q_8$ and $D_8$: extension of $\Bbb Z_2$ by a group of exponent $2$): OP's $[,]$ algebra captures commutators only, whereas the extension also depends on squares. I am not trying to classify all possible extensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not familiar with the term Carnot algebra, do you know any reference for it?

Comment: Actually I will be interested in some theorems concerning Carnot algebras. For example, if the Carnot algebra of a group $G$ satisfy some property $A$, then the group satisfy some property $B$, etc.

Comment: No, sorry. What I wrote is just some common knowledge/common sense. I've never tried to go into the details.

Comment: @Zuriel: there's no point in posting twice the same comment... for your second question maybe you could specify the kind of properties you'd like. If $G$ is a finite nilpotent group then the associated Carnot algebra retains the cardinal and the nilpotency length (as well as the cardinal of all terms in the central series).

Comment: Thanks @YCor for the information. I have just finished computing the Carnot algebra for some groups and am wondering if I can obtain some information of those groups by observing the Carnot algebra. Thus I would really appreciate if someone can recommend me some materials on Carnot algebras, containing not only the definition but also some properties.